# node.js, process.kill() and process.exit(0), which one can kill process?

Tags: node.js

I read node.js docs. It says:

> Even though the name of this function is `process.kill()`, it is really just a signal sender, as the kill system call. The signal sent may do something other than killing the target process.

```js
console.log('current process id: ', process.pid);

process.on('SIGHUP', function() {
  console.log('Got SIGHUP signal');
});

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('Exiting...');
  process.exit(0);  //kill process
  console.log('Process id that has exited: ', process.pid); //does not output
}, 1000);

process.kill(process.pid, 'SIGHUP'); //does not kill process
console.log('Id of the process exiting: ', process.pid); //so this output normally
```

output:

```
current process id:  64520
Id of the process exiting:  64520
Got SIGHUP signal
Exiting...
```

It seems `process.exit(0)` is the one which kills `node.js` process.

Answer (score 4):

It all depends on the situation that you're in. Like Gospal Joshi said `process.exit([code])` is useful to end the process very quickly. But in other cases you may want to pass a **signal** to that process before shutdown for cleanup/graceful shutdown. For example if you are listening to signal events such as:

```
process.on('SIGINT', () => {
  //do something
}
```

it allows you to run cleanup or gracefully shutdown the process vs exiting instantly without doing anything.

`Also, note that Node.js establishes signal handlers for SIGINT and SIGTERM and Node.js processes will not terminate immediately due to receipt of those signals. Rather, Node.js will perform a sequence of cleanup actions and then will re-raise the handled signal` - [Node Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_event_exit)

Answer (score 2):

`process.kill(pid, [ code ])` shines on concurrent applications with multiple processes (since you can just plug in the pid of the process you wish to kill and it does it).

`process.exit()` is sufficient and most common if you dont have a usecase that requires killing any other process than the main node process.

Personally, I recommend you to use `process.exit()` unless you really have to kill another process (pid different than `process.pid`)

Answer (score 1):

Use `process.exit()`, It ends the process with the specified code. Calling `process.exit()` will force the process to exit as quickly as possible even if there are still asynchronous operations pending

**Syntax:**
**`process.exit([code])`**

Links:

1. [Exit codes](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_exit_codes)
2. [Exit() Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code)

Comment: what's the purpose of using `process.kill()`?